# How to solve mingw32-make.exe : *** [ALL] Error 2 in Codelite?

Tags: c++, codelite

[image]

please how to solve this issue in codelite .

Comment: Please copy the log as text instead of posting pictures. Apparently the IDE can't find the compiler/tools. Stand-alone Mingw might need to be added to PATH manually. Also, I don't think mingw32 is maintained any longer, so maybe consider dropping that for mingw64.

Comment: Looks like codelite doesn't handle spaces in filenames

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, typically in order to help we need more information, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for help to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved that issue error is occurring because of **CodeLite** doesn't handle spaces between workspace and file names.